# Given an ode $x'=e^{-x}\sin(x)$, initial condition is $x(0)=-2\pi$. Why the x(t) is not a straight line in the graph x vs t?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fixed-points

**Question:**

Given an ode $x'=e^{-x}\sin(x)$, initial condition is $x(0)=-2\pi$. Why the x(t) is not a straight line in the graph x vs t?

**Thoughts:**

I found out the fixed points, $x=-2\pi$ is one of the unstable fixed points. Which means the velocity is 0 at that point.

Which means if its initially there, it should never move. Then it should be a straight line in the graph.
Am I correct?

**Situation:**

But when I draw it in python its not the case::

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# function that returns dx/dt
def dxdt(x, t):
    return np.exp(-x)*np.sin(x)

# time points
t = np.linspace(0,20, 100)

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [15, 6]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

# initial condition
x0 = -2*np.pi
# solve ODE
x = odeint(dxdt,x0,t)

# plot results
ax.plot(t, x)

ax.set(xlabel='time', ylabel='x(t)')
import matplotlib.ticker as tck
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(tck.FuncFormatter(
   lambda val,pos: '{:.0g}$\pi$'.format(val/np.pi) if val !=0 else '0'
))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(tck.MultipleLocator(base=np.pi))
```

[image: x0=-2pi]

For more initial conditions, x(t) is actually not in -2pi, -4pi, ... when time is positive :

[image: given more x0]

Why is that?

Comment: $x'(-2\pi)= 0$ is not equal to "not moving forever". Maybe the object start from rest, but there is a force accelerating it.

Comment: @FormerMath But its initially at rest $x(0)=-2\pi$, then shouldn't it not move?

Comment: In general, given an ODE $x'=f(x(t))$ for some $f$ and $f(x(0))=0,$ then $x(t)=x(0)$ for all $t$ is a solution to the differential equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with numerical errors:

```
np.exp(2*np.pi)*np.sin(-2*np.pi)=1.31157628381704e-13
```

This is not zero. You can do something like:

```
# function that returns dx/dt
def dxdt(x, t):
    r = np.exp(-x)*np.sin(x)
    if np.abs(r)<1e-10:
       r=0
    return r
```

Comment: So in theory, it should be a straight line, not moving at all $\forall t \in \left( { - \infty ,\infty } \right)$, right?

Comment: Correct. But since you have a small numerical error, and the solution is unstable, it will diverge from the expected result.

Comment: So even for the $x(0)=\pi$ case, its actually not a straight line, it just looks like a straight line then. Wonder is there a possible way to fix it.

Comment: in your function `dxdt`, check if absolute value of the derivative is less than say `1e-10`, and return 0 if it is.

Comment: Yeah, I searched up in last 20min on how to deal with these, I tried `if (np.allclose(0, dxdt)):`, it worked for $x(0)=-2\pi$, but need to be careful with the bounds of the errors. I have to use `if np.abs(dxdt)<1e-5:` for initial conditions $x(0)$ that are larger than $-4\pi$. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646477/why-is-sin180-not-zero-when-using-python-and-numpy